# Replace string in file on Solaris using sed

Tags: bash, unix, sed, solaris

I'm trying to modify a file using sed. Example file:

*apples*
*bananas*
*oranges*
*pears*

Using sed I've got:

```
sed -e '/oranges/i\cherries' -e '1,$s/A/a/' fruit.txt
```

This just echoes the output to the terminal. The output is in the required format (cherries after bananas, before oranges).

How can I use sed to make the permanent change to the file *fruits.txt?*

Comment: `sed 'command' file > tmp && mv tmp file`

Comment: That worked, thanks!

Comment: Add option `i`:    sed -i -e '/oranges/i\cherries' -e '1,$s/A/a/' fruit.txt

Comment: @zombic -`i` is an illegal option on Solaris 10. Need GNU sed for that.

Comment: ups, I didn't know :)